# Want to access the Strings from a List<List<String>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a `List<List<String>> listFinal`. According to input, it has 2 lists and those lists has couple of strings. I have to access those strings. I tried to make a listIterator for listFinal.

```
ListIterator<List<String>> LIS=  listFinal.listIterator();
```

And another listIterator for the lists of finalList, so that I can access the strings inside. using:

```
ListIterator<String> SLIS= LIS.listIterator();
```

having this error:

```
cannot find symbol: method listIterator()
  location: variable LIS of type ListIterator<List<String>>
```

on the line I declared SLIS.

Comment: Why do you want to use iterator manually instead of leting `for-each` loop do it for you?

Comment: I tried with 'for(String str:listFinal.get(i))' but i don't know how to get to the strings without knowing index. listFinal.get(i) takes me to the list of strings not the strings.

Comment: "listFinal.get(i) takes me to the list of strings not the strings" yes, and as you noticed `for(String str: listFinal.get(i))` will let you iterate over all strings from that list. If you want to iterate over all string from all you will need nested loops: one which will pick all lists, second which will pick all elements from each list.

Comment: I made the outer loop: for(int i=0;i<listFinal.size();i++) and inner loop: for(String lstr:listFinal.get(i)); which should be my Strings. but, System.out.println(lstr) is not showing anything. why?  Really dumb question.  @Pshemo

Comment: Is this semicolon after right after `for(String lstr:listFinal.get(i));` also in your original code? Also are you sure that `listFinal` list is not empty? Did you try invoking `System.out.println(listFinal)`?

Comment: BTW you can also use for-each like `for(List<String> row : listFinal)` `for(String lstr : row)`.

Comment: Thanks! there was problem in my other code. listFinal was empty. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

`ListIterator` doesn't have `listIterator()` method.

What you need is,

```
LIS.next().listIterator();
```

And that probably inside a loop.